# How to fit 2 experimental data to derivative equations with scipy? - Solved

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit 2 experimental data at the same time, since it has some shared parameters. It is a chemical reaction and I would expect to get the fitting as shown in the image attached. I have managed to fit my data using symfit package, however I will need to do with scipy/numpy in order to further treat the data (with monte carlo simulations) The code I have tried with scipy is:

[GL conversion to GM and fitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzbbk.png)

[Dataset for download](https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=be12b49b-b34b-4254-8416-18356a111df9)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

# Open dataset from txt file after extraction from brute data:
with open("ydata.txt", "r") as csv_file:
    ydata = np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter = ',')

with open("ydata2.txt", "r") as csv_file:
    ydata2 = np.loadtxt(csv_file, delimiter = ',')

xdata = np.arange(0, len(ydata))
fulldata = np.column_stack([ydata,ydata2])


# Define the equation considering the enzymatic reaction Gl -> Gm with the HP decay.
def f(C, t, k, a, b):
    GL = ydata
    GM = ydata2
    
    dGLdt = -k*GL - GL/a
    dGMdt = k*GL - GM/b
    
    return [dGLdt, dGMdt] 

guess = (1e-3, 10, 10,1 )

popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, fulldata, guess)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
  File "/Users/karensantos/Desktop/Codes/Stack_question.py", line 52, in <module>
    popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, fulldata, guess)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 784, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 410, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 24, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 484, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,98) (98,2)
```

I can resolve one equation at a time with curve_fit, but I need to fit together to find all the correct shared parameter (k) and since GM is dependent of GL (product and substrate, respectively).

How can I fit both experimental data using scipy optimization?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the arrays in a 1D array to run with `curve_fit`

I can't run your example so I will make one

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def cost(x, a, b):
    return np.hstack(f(a, b, x))
def f(a,b,x):
    return a * x**3, a**2*np.exp(-(x-b/a)**2/a)
x = np.linspace(-2, 2)
y1, y2 = f(4.5, 2.3, x)
initial_guess = (1,1)
params, _ = curve_fit(cost, x, np.hstack([y1, y2]),initial_guess)
print(params)
```

In this example there is a function f that takes two parameters and the x data, I use it to compute (y1, y2) and then I use `curve_fit` to determine which parameters generated the (y1, y2).

### Edit 1

Using the data provided by the OP, a fit could be this

```py
def f(params, xdata, ydata, ydata2):
    C = xdata
    t, k, a, b = params
    GL = ydata
    GM = ydata2
    
    dGLdt = -k*GL - GL/a
    dGMdt = k*GL - GM/b
    
    return np.hstack([dGLdt, dGMdt])

guess = (1e-3, 10, 10,1)

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.leastsq(f, guess, args=(xdata, ydata, ydata2))
```

And the choice of parameters is `[ 1.00000000e-03, -1.71943255e-69,  1.60693865e+61,  1.60694078e+60]`, a trivial solution, having (`a`,`b`) growing to infinity and `k` going to zero. `t` is not changed because the objective function does not change with `t`.

I think you should reconsider your model equations.

Comment: thank you for your time and tip. 

Indeed, I tried to simplify my code but it was still messy. I have updated and I am providing data so anybody could try it. I tried to concatenate my multiple dataset (ydata and ydata), however as my equation is a derivative I get an error about the shape when is trying to minimize. 

How should I define the equation in this case?

Comment: One year later feedback, the suggestion by Bob worked quite well in this case. IT was just a matter of concatenating correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Karen from your feedback, in this case you should consider accepting the answer, have a look in the stack [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)